# Anaconda3にkerasをインストールしたところ、PyCharmの挙動がおかしくなりました。

Tags: python, keras, pycharm

Anaconda3にkerasをインストールしたところ、PyCharmの挙動がおかしくなりました。

とりあえず何をやっても以下のメッセージが出てきます。
「UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeRegressor from version 0.22 when using version 0.22.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.  UserWarning)」

最近行ったことは、
tensorflowとkerasをインストールしました。
またpandasとseabornのアップデートも行いました。
tensorflowとkerasのインストールの際、conda installだったか、pip installだったかは忘れてしまいました。

いろいろ調べて調べてを繰り返してみたのですが、知識が追いつかないページも多く、とりあえず以下ページ
https://qiita.com/uminor/items/b2cd07401aa403b7ff82
の話の要領で「keras_activate.bat」を修正することでなんとかなるのかもしれないと、試してみようと思ったのですが、「keras_activate.bat」というファイルが見つかりません。私のpcの場合「・・・\conda\activate.d」ディレクトリに「activate.bat」というファイルがあるだけです。テキストエディタで開いてみても「set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"」という記述もありませんでした。また同じディレクトリも存在しなく
「C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.8.2-py37_0\info\test\tests\test-recipes\activate_deactivate_package\src\etc\conda\activate.d」にあったものです。

tensorflowとkerasはUninstallを行ってみましたが問題は解決しませんでした。
現在は再度インストした状態です。

自分なりにいろいろ調べ尽くしてどうにもならないのでだいぶ参っています。
どなたかアドバイスや解決方法などをご教授いただけたらと思います。
よろしくお願いします。

Windows7 64bit
Pycharm community 2019.2
環境です。

Comment: scikit-learnはインストールされてますか？また，tensorflowとkerasのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？

Comment: 書き込みありがとうございます。
scikit-learnはAnaconda3に入っていたものをそのまま使用しています。tensorflowとkerasは3日前にインストールしたものなので最新のものかと思います。

Comment: 実際に見てみないと詳細はわからないですが，エラーから察するになんかのパッケージのバージョンが対応していないのでしょう．調べたところscikit-learnのエラーみたいなので，scikit-learnを再インストールしてみたらどうなるでしょうか？．また，pipとanacondaを併用するのは良くないのでどちらかに絞ったほうが良いかと思います．

Comment: 書き込みありがとうございます。
今回のことでpipとanacondaを併用するのは良くないとの話を知りました。こんな落とし穴があるとは、、、という感じです。それから長くなるので省いてしまっていたのですが、エラーメッセージはscikit-learn以外のモジュールでも似たようなメッセージが出る状態です。Pandasやseabornのアップデートを行ったのもそのためでした。
もうAnacondaとPycharm 自体の再インストールしかないのかな～と思いながらカックリしています。